# How to prevent viewing website code

Tags: html

I have a website that has a lot of data and that is sensitive to the website so I made a code that prevents right clicks but if you are using Safari it is  easy to see the data I need to hide the info also so safari cant view it ether.

Comment: Anything you send to the client, in this case the browser, should be perceived as sending plain text. If you are trying to hide something then I recommend not sending it :(

Comment: The browser needs to know what to display.. if you hide it, you are also hiding it from the viewer.

Comment: Disabling right click isn't security, it's just annoying your users. Any browser that doesn't let you disable this is worthless, but sites that do it in the first place are terrible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I m not sure if there is a completely safe solution.

if its images, use flash to load them dynamically.

- yet people who knows swf-bin specs can decompile your swf files and find out the real image path.

if its data & text.

as much I can do is to

1: use pure js to render all views.

- use XMLHttpRequest/ActiveXObject to load data and import these ajax js code @ runtime.
- compress your js/css code before deploy
- [here](http://skillmeetup.com) is one of my mockups

2: on the server side

- check the request header to drop command line request.
- exchange cookie/session key for each time.

BUT, this will make google-bots don't know how to inspect your site.

so DON'T do that on your landing page.

Answer (score 3):

Client side, you cannot secure your code from view. Firebug will still show the code. You should have sensitive data on the Server.

Comment: Like MySQL or phpmyadmin

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

If the data is sufficiently sensitive that people shouldn't be able to view it, don't put it on a web site.